how to capture "carriage returns" from output file in c programming language
I am having problems capturing carriage returns from an input file.
I'm supposed to open a file, find the average word length, then print all the words that are longer than the average. But on words that are followed by a return, I am not capturing.
For instance, I have properly returned all words except for the ones with the "newline" symbol after it, which I will show here as italicized and with a less than symbol. Periods and commas are capturing fine.
Dijkstra,
*CACM,\<*
*15:10\<*
people
belittle
ambitions.
*Small\<*
people
*always\<*
that,
really
great
become
great.

Here is my code. I can't figure out how to include words that are followed by a "return":
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 30
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 2048

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    int total_length = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    int max_word_length = 0;
    char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1) {
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (isalnum(word[i])) {
                length++;
            }
        }
        if (length > 0) { 
            total_length += length;
            word_count++;
            if (length > max_word_length) {
                max_word_length = length;
            }
        }
    }


    int average_length = 0;
    if (word_count > 0) {
        average_length = total_length / word_count;
    }


    rewind(file);

    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1) {
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (isalnum(word[i])) { // Check if character is alphanumeric
                length++;
            }
        }
        if (length > average_length) {
            printf("%s\n", word);
        }
    }
    //printf("\n");

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}    
    


Try using fgetline followed by sscanf instead of using fscanf.  You will have to loop differently.

The scanf() family reads words with %s.  You want to us %c to read white space characters.

When I run it, I get 10 lines printed ie the average length is 5 so people and really are printed but great isn't long enough. What operating system are you using? Like cup, I would consider using fgetline instead of fscanf. You could also try calling fopen with mode "rb" rather than just "r".
